# Can you use "onset" as an adjective?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

The following excerpt is from a film review by Elizabeth Kerr:

> A sensual May-December romance between a popular romance writer and her student-turned-assistant takes a tragic turn when her early **onset** Alzheimer's asserts itself in *Butterfly Sleep*...

"Onset" is a noun but it seems it is used as an adjective here. Or are you allowed to have two nouns (onset and Alzheimer's) in a row?

How could you write this sentence differently, using "onset" in a simpler way, so I didn't have to debate if using two nouns were a problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: "Early onset Alzheimer's" is a particular manifestation of Alzheimer's disease.

Comment: Lots of nouns are used adjectivally. "I've just been attending to my car radio". In this case of a compound pre-position adjective, many people (including myself) would use a hyphen - "...when her early-onset Alzheimer's asserts itself..."

Comment: 'Onset' is not, to my knowledge, used attributively, but 'early[-]onset' is a well-known compound premodifier in this context. Compare _fast breeder_ 
 in _fast breeder reactor_.

Comment: A Google search for "early onset Alzheimer's" is required. A refined search for "onset Alzheimer's" -"early-onset Alzheimer's" shows classmates such as "younger-onset Alzheimer's" and "late-onset Alzheimer's". But probably no non-compound examples. A search for "early-onset"  + "meaning" is thus indicated. / Just looking up 'onset' at Longmans leads you to the answer. / Research is required to be shown where it may reasonably be expected. / The attributive use of nouns has been addressed far too often on ELU. It is an extremely common, but not a totally productive feature of English.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question because _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) and _The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language_, fifth edition (2010)—the most recent editions of these two standard U.S. references—have no entry for _onset_ as an adjective and no entry for _early[-]onset_ as a set phrase. When reasonable basic research fails to yield an answer to a poster's question, I think it is disingenuous to tell the poster, in effect, "if you had done the appropriate basic research, you would have found the answer you are looking for."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _Onset_ is used attributively, though perhaps not about Alzheimer’s. In phonetics, _onset position_ is quite common.

Comment: @Sven Yargs 'Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) and The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, fifth edition (2010)—the most recent editions of these two standard U.S. references—have no entry for onset as an adjective / modifier and no entry for early[-]onset as a set phrase.' would validate the question. I see **no** signs of **any** research. I believe the disingenuousness to lie elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

**Onset** is not being used as an adjective here. The adjective is **“early onset”**, which would perhaps have been better hyphenated as **“early-onset”** for clarity. As such the combination has a specific clinical temporal meaning. Thus, the [Oxford Dictionaries online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/early-onset) gives the definition:

> **early-onset**
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> (Of a medical condition) occurring relatively early in life,
>   especially as compared to a different form of the same condition; of,
>   relating to, or affected by such a condition.
>
> *Origin*
>
> 1950s; earliest
>   use found in Proceedings of the Royal Society of Medicine.

Comment: Please (a) don't answer questions on ELU where the OP should have done the basic research themself / (b) don't confuse ODO (to which you link) with OED (online or otherwise).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — (b) Changed. (a) It is only your subjective opinion that this is the case. What is clear is that I have followed SE policy of answering a question as an answer, not as a comment. This is in contrast to the two "comments" to the question which are clearly answers and against explicit SE policy. If you are going to upbraid members for contravening SE policy, you might direct your fire to the right quarter.

Comment: I was merely extending the courtesy of explaining my downvote. Most people complain when they receive unexplained downvotes. // Hopefully, other users will add to the 3 closevotes so far attaching to this question. There are 2 000 000 hits on Google for a search for early + onset. ELU is a site aimed at linguists, not beginners, and some users strive to maintain standards. Performing dictionary and other simple and obvious searches for people hardly adds to the site's credibility.

Comment: To quote [Mari-Lou A in Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4557/answering-questions-in-comments): 'Nearly everybody does it. Write answers. In comments.' In answer to anongoodnurse's 'However, I feel a bit silly answering some questions in Answers.' And Reg Dwight has said: '[W]e write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  “To quote Mari-Lou A in Meta: 'Nearly everybody does it.” Surely there are older instances of the use of  this phrase. I imagine the moneylenders said the same thing to Christ in the temple. I do not claim to be Christ, but *I* most definitely do *not* do it, [nor am I the only one](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2653/why-are-answers-being-posted-in-the-comments-on-the-question) who finds this reprehensible.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So you were explaining a down vote. And of course by writing an answer as an answer, unlike abusing the comment facility, one is exposing oneself to down votes. Fine. The poster and others can gauge whether the answer is good or not — which is how Stack Exchange is supposed to work. But aren’t down votes supposed to indicate an answer is incorrect? You seem to be saying you down voted because you don’t think I should have answered at all. However I suppose “nearly everybody does it”.

Comment: MetaEd, a moderator, [writes](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3428/how-long-should-a-questionable-question-remain-open/3447#3447) 'A question lacking [reasonable] research should be closed until the research work is done, then reopened.' Before you start questioning my attempts to keep the site above the basic level or even the mediocre, perhaps you could address this.

Comment: Since I was the commenter who provided an "answer", perhaps I should justify this rather than rely on @Edwin Ashworh to take up the cudgels. If a question addresses a very simple, beginners understanding of English I do one of two things. Either I suggest they go to ELL. Or if it is borderline I give an explanation in comments, as I did here. For an experienced native speaker to provide a formal answer, would seem to be ungentlemanly, a bit like potting your opponents ball in billiards.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — Addressing "this". It is the function of the review process to determine whether a question fulfils the criterion you cite. No doubt you voted to close. However until there are 5 votes to close it is only your opinion that the question satisfies those criteria, and there is no reason anyone else should conform to that opinion, even if you had expressed it in a comment of the type "I am voting to close because..." which you did not.

Comment: @WS2 — But you are under no obligation to comment or answer. If a question deserves to be moved to ELL (which one might argue this does) you can just vote to do so in the review queue and wait until others support you.

Comment: As for my compatriot @Edwin Ashworth, I think likening his actions to "the money changers in the temple" is stretching things a little, even though I am aware he is a Lancastrian, and hence a bit suspect!

Comment: @WS2 — A Lancastrian indeed! Well perhaps as a Yorkshireman I should let this drop. A Merry Christmas to us all.

Comment: @David But I incline to answer, since one of my purposes in being here is to try and help people. Some non-native speakers e.g. Chinese, make Herculean efforts to learn English - and since I am retired and have the odd few minutes to spare, I try to be of help where I can.

Comment: @David As a Norfolk peasant I have no wish to become embroiled in a War of the Roses. (Though those Norfolk gentry I have studied, did support the Duke of Lancaster in that celebrated contest).Happy Christmas.